# Schedule run a jar file in command prompt

Tags: jar

I want to run a jar file on every Monday that can be executed from command prompt only not by mouse double click. I have used windows task scheduler and it is showing the last run time of file but it is not able to perform the desired action!

Comment: What does your command for the scheduled task look like ? Something like `java -jar yourjar.jar` ?

Comment: yes exactly and in command prompt i am getting the desired result